# Creating Monthly Data From Seasonal Factors and Annual Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

1. table of multiplicative seasonal factors for each month
2. table of annual budget amounts

I would like a T-SQL solution to create a third table that explodes (multiplies) the annual budget amounts into a monthly time series.

Example of Table 1 (seasonal factors):

| Month | Seasonal Factor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | .08 |
| 2 | .075 |
| 3 | .065 |
| 4 | .085 |
| 5 | .09 |
| 6 | .08 |
| 7 | .08 |
| 8 | .075 |
| 9 | .065 |
| 10 | .085 |
| 11 | .09 |
| 12 | .13 |

Example of Table 2 (annual budget amounts)

| Year | Budget |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | 250,000 |
| 2020 | 275,000 |

Desired Solution

| Month | Imputed Budget |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | .08 * 250,000 |
| 2019-02-01 | .075 * 250,000 |
| ... | ... |
| 2020-12-01 | .13 * 275,000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be describing a `cross join`:

```
select datefromparts(t2.year, t1.month, 1) as month,
       t1.factor * t2.budget
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2
order by month;
```

Comment: @JoelSherman . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: So sorry.  I neglected to describe that the [Year] in t2 above is a fiscal year, beginning on July and ending June.  The cross-join works perfect if distributing the annual amount by calendar months, but won't work with fiscal years.

Comment: @JoelSherman . . . This answers the question you asked here.  The best thing to do is to (re)accept this answer and then ask a new question.